# Can´t add products to CodeIgniter Cart from another view

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.2.2 with HMVC and a custom session library

I have two views I'll call them V1.php and V2.php for simplicity
and in each view I have a product that can be added to the cart via ajax when you click on the button:

```
<button class="add-to-cart" id="123" type="button" class="btn btn-fefault cart">
```

both V1.php and V2.php are sending product details to a controller cart.php to the method add() via ajax
and here is the ajax call  in both V1.php and V2.php

```
$(".add-to-cart").click(function()
{
    var target_url = '<?php echo(base_url()."cart/add") ; ?>';
    var prod_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var qty = 1;
    // prepare the data to be sent
    var ProductData = {product_id:prod_id,quantity:qty};

    $.ajax(
    {
        url : target_url,
        type: "POST",
        data : ProductData,
        success: function(data)
        {

            cart = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);
            $("#cart_num").html("( " + cart.num_of_items + " )");

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            $("#cart_notice").show();
            $("#cart_notice").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
        }
    });

    // prevent default
    return false;
});
```

and here is the controller cart.php

```
public function add()
{
    $product_id =  $this->input->post('product_id');
    $quantity =  $this->input->post('quantity');

    // prepare the array for the cart
    $data = array(
           'id'      => $product_id,
           'qty'     => $quantity,
           'price'   => 39.95,
           'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
           'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
        );

    // insert the array in the cart 
    $cart_flag = $this->cart->insert($data);
    //$cart_flag returns false if something went wrong 
    //$cart_flag returns an id if everything is ok 

    // prepare the array for the ajax callback function
    $cart = array(
    'num_of_items' => $this->cart->total_items(),
    'total_price' => $this->cart->total()
    );

    echo json_encode($cart);
}
```

thanks to debugging tools I could see that :

1.when I add the product from V1.php everything is fine ($cart_flag returns an id)

but

2.when I add the product from V2.php it doesn't add anything ($cart_flag returns FALSE )  although $data is the same in both cases

what I'm I doing wrong ?

Comment: It's very hard to say since we only have the part of the code that you say is working. Try reducing V2 to a simple case that always fails, then (if you didn't solve your bug in the process) update your question with this minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was casting, it really gave me a hard time but at last I found it, 
the $data looked the same but the type was not

this fixes the problem

```
$data = array(
           'id'      => (int)$product_id,
           'qty'     => (int)$quantity,
           'price'   => 39.95,
           'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
           'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
        );
```

hope this helps someone else with the same issue